# How do you identify a set of character and numbers and a group consisting symbol using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a string using a regex for the following requirement
its a file path (unix) which should not contain any symbol, whitespace etc.

1. String that starts with ./
2. String ends with .xml
3. Allowed char = a-zA-Z_-0-9./ and a group @@ENV
4. @@ENV can be used anywhere in the file name

I'm new to regex and I managed to identify using this regex below, it covers only the first scenario, i want the text before and after `@@ENV` group to be captured and they should be optional.

```
/^(.\/[a-zA-Z_\-0-9\.]+)+(@@ENV)\.(xml)$/
```

Eg. scenarios

1. './app/settings/conf-@@ENV.xml'
2. './app/settings/@@ENV-conf.xml'
3. './app/settings/system-@@ENV-conf.xml'
4. './app/settings/@@ENV.xml'

I have a added a sample code to test on jsfiddle below

Resources:

- JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u4pcnbLz/3/
- Online Regex tool: https://regex101.com/

Comment: In #3 you state `Allowed char = a-zA-Z_-0-9. and a group @@ENV`. But each of your examples also seem to allow `/`.

Comment: [`^\.\/([a-zA-Z_\-0-9.\/]+)+@@ENV.*?\.xml$`](https://regex101.com/r/eB0H1d/1) See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u4pcnbLz/4/)

Comment: I've missed it i have updated the question. Thanks Moishe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/7ZNsm9/1) like this:

```
(\.\/(?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*))@@ENV((?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*)\.xml)
```

To explain what's going on here:

```
(\.\/(?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*))
```

has an inner non capturing group `(?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*)` that matches any letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens, or forward slash zero or more times. The outer (capturing) group also contains `\.\/` which first matches one period followed by one forward slash.

After matching `@@ENV`:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*)\.xml)
```

has an inner non capturing group `(?:[a-zA-Z_0-9-\/]*)` that matches any letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens, or forward slash zero or more times. The outer (capturing) group also contains `\.xml` which afterwards matches one period followed by the word `xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work.

Regex: `^\.\/([a-z\/\-]+)@@ENV[a-z\/\-]*(\.xml)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UnvbC1/1)